# Parameter changes original value

Tags: c#, list, reference

I guess it is stupid question but if You can take a look

Here is my method

```
 public Tuple CheckRoyalFlush()
        {
            List<Honours> flush = new List<Honours>()
            {
                Honours.Ace,
                Honours.King,
                Honours.Queen,
                Honours.Jack,
                Honours.Ten
            };

            if (RoyalFlushJokerHelper(honoursOnTheScreen, flush) || ContainsAllItems(honoursOnTheScreen, flush))
            {
                Suits suit = cardsOnTheScreen.ElementAt(0).GetSuit();
                foreach (Card card in cardsOnTheScreen.Skip(1))
                {
                    if (card.GetSuit() != suit)
                    {
                        if (card.GetHonour() == Honours.Joker)
                            continue;
                        else
                            return new Tuple(false, null);
                    }
                }
                return new Tuple(true, new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
            }
```

The thing is when I am checking my "If" I get to the first method " RoyalFlushJokerHelper" and there I am deleting all my 5 items from flush list.

Then the problem is when i step into ContainAllItems method my flush list is empty.

I am not passing it by reference so why does the first method changes my original list ?

Comment: What makes you believe you do not pass it via reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# only these objects are value-types:

- Numeric data types
- Boolean, Char, and Date
- `struct`s
- `enum`s
- Long, Byte, UShort, UInteger, or ULong

All other objects are reference-types and when you pass them to a function, you pass it **as reference**.
If you want to change your `List` without affecting it, you can clone it before:

```
public bool RoyalFlushJokerHelper(object honoursOnTheScreen, List<Honours> honours)
{
    var honoursCopy = honours.Clone();
    // work with honoursCopy
}
```

Please, read some information about values types and reference types.
For example, take a look at [MSDN article "Value Types and Reference Types"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

Comment: class objects are reference-type is not true because premitive type also derived from that type only. its parent of all type in .net

Comment: @PranayRana I didn't mean `object`s. I meant `class objects` - the objects which are classes. Probably, I named it wrong. Anyway, I have fixed an answer. Please, if you don't mind, review it and let me know if something's wrong.